# Async foreign tables, foreign data wrapper

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper, multicorn

i am working on foreign data wrappers in postgres, using multicorn and using triggers to insert data in foreign tables, however i do not want the postgres to wait for response after trigger, just trigger inserts it and then forgets. 
how can that be possible.

Actually i am using it for a foreign table

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE media_es (
    id BIGINT,
    title TEXT,
    description TEXT,
    tags TEXT,
    query TEXT,
    score NUMERIC
  )
  SERVER multicorn_es
  OPTIONS (
      host 'elasticsearch',  
      port '9200',
      index 'test',
      type 'media',
      rowid_column 'id',
      query_column 'query',
      score_column 'score'
  );


CREATE TRIGGER es_insert_media
      AFTER INSERT
          ON media
      FOR EACH ROW
          EXECUTE PROCEDURE index_media();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION index_media()
      RETURNS trigger
      AS $def$
          BEGIN
          INSERT INTO media_es
                (
                  id,
                  title,
                  description,
                  tags
              )
          VALUES
              (
                  NEW.id,
                  NEW.title,
                  NEW.description,
                  NEW.tags
              )
          ;
          RETURN NEW;  
      END;
  $def$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: @VaoTsun i am using trigger in postgres and dont want any response from trigger. Rather use the asynchronous calls to the trigger. Just call the trigger and forget it.

Comment: I do not get any response from the trigger. That is fine. But it still waits to complete the execution. I dont want it ti even wait. @VaoTsun

Comment: Yea. Thats right @VaoTsun

Comment: You said "dont wait for it to end" how is that possible. Can you elaborate a little bit.  @VaoTsun

Comment: Sure. Editing my post

Comment: @VaoTsun Editted

Comment: aha - now I get your async problem I think. mind using dblink for insert instead - not fdw

Comment: FDW  is used on purpose, because of its performance and connection persistence. @VaoTsun

Comment: @VaoTsun is there any way using FDW

Comment: dunno. I used dblink for async operations. not sure if there is any other monkey hack for it

Comment: will Notify/Listen framework workout here? @VaoTsun

Comment: with some pervercy level. but it won't be about FDW either - the insert wont be performed by trigger function, but by other code - same as if you put dblink insert inside your trigger function - so I dont see how it is different

Comment: the whole idea is to put `perform async_call(NEW);` INSTEAD of actual insert to trigger function. and how you implement async_call - is totally different question

Comment: ok. thanks  . @VaoTsun

Answer (score 0):

postgres [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/dblink.html) extension allows async calls to remote server via [dblink-send-query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/contrib-dblink-send-query.html) command.

not sure how it will work within trigger in terms of establishing multiple connections. caution should be taken here for resource leakage